# Graphics problem in some applications (Spotify, Skype, VLC) on Ubuntu 22.04.03

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, skype, spotify

Some days ago I started having graphics problems (not sure how else to describe it, check the attached screenshot to see what it looks like) when I open some applications, i.e. Spotify, Skype, VLC. Skype I've just installed, but the other two have never given me any problems.
When I open Spotify via terminal, I get the following error:

```
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
Warning: vkCreateInstance failed with VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER
    at CheckVkSuccessImpl (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/VulkanError.cpp:88)
    at CreateVkInstance (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/BackendVk.cpp:458)
    at Initialize (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/BackendVk.cpp:344)
    at Create (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/BackendVk.cpp:266)
    at operator() (../../third_party/dawn/src/dawn/native/vulkan/BackendVk.cpp:521)
```

And the error I get with Skype is:

```
+ [ -f /home/julian/snap/skype/common/.config/skypeforlinux/settings.json ]
+ export SKYPE_LOGS=/home/julian/snap/skype/326/logs
+ [ ! -d /home/julian/snap/skype/326/logs ]
+ exec /snap/skype/326/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux

(skypeforlinux:10458): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:23:07.018: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1422:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(skypeforlinux:10458): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:23:07.023: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3308:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(skypeforlinux:10458): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:23:07.024: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3770:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
[10458:0206/002308.417424:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Inhibit: object_path= /org/freedesktop/login1: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.199" (uid=1000 pid=10458 comm="/snap/skype/326/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforli" label="snap.skype.skype (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="Inhibit" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=859 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind " label="unconfined")
[10458:0206/002308.418670:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Inhibit: object_path= /org/freedesktop/login1: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.199" (uid=1000 pid=10458 comm="/snap/skype/326/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforli" label="snap.skype.skype (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="Inhibit" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=859 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind " label="unconfined")
[10458:0206/002310.348837:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented
[10458:0206/002310.350346:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.246" (uid=1000 pid=10458 comm="/snap/skype/326/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforli" label="snap.skype.skype (enforce)") interface="org.gnome.ScreenSaver" member="GetActive" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.gnome.ScreenSaver" (uid=1000 pid=1904 comm="/usr/bin/gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.Scre" label="unconfined")
Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored credentials fetched from keytar.
    at /snap/skype/326/usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar/main.js:2:523993
    at async node:electron/js2c/browser_init:193:551
Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored credentials fetched from keytar.
    at /snap/skype/326/usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar/main.js:2:523993
    at async node:electron/js2c/browser_init:193:551
Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored credentials fetched from keytar.
    at /snap/skype/326/usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar/main.js:2:523993
    at async node:electron/js2c/browser_init:193:551
Error occurred in handler for 'GUEST_VIEW_MANAGER_CALL': Error: ERR_ABORTED (-3) loading 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?app_version=8.112.0.206&client_flight=ReservedFlight33,suhs&client_id=00000000480BC46C&cobrandid=6e63daac-8dfe-43f6-b70e-deacb69a89d6&display=touch&fl=phone2&lw=1&mkt=es-MX&nopa=2&psi=skype&uaid=9fd2f7c2d3254bd3bf0ece157823be1b&coa=1&scope=service::lw.skype.com::MBI_SSL&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.live.com%2Foauth20_desktop.srf'
    at rejectAndCleanup (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:7810)
    at EventEmitter.navigationListener (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:8116)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:538:35) {
  errno: -3,
  code: 'ERR_ABORTED',
  url: 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?app_version=8.112.0.206&client_flight=ReservedFlight33,suhs&client_id=00000000480BC46C&cobrandid=6e63daac-8dfe-43f6-b70e-deacb69a89d6&display=touch&fl=phone2&lw=1&mkt=es-MX&nopa=2&psi=skype&uaid=9fd2f7c2d3254bd3bf0ece157823be1b&coa=1&scope=service::lw.skype.com::MBI_SSL&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.live.com%2Foauth20_desktop.srf'
}
Error occurred in handler for 'GUEST_VIEW_MANAGER_CALL': Error: ERR_ABORTED (-3) loading 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?app_version=8.112.0.206&client_flight=ReservedFlight33,suhs&client_id=00000000480BC46C&cobrandid=6e63daac-8dfe-43f6-b70e-deacb69a89d6&display=touch&fl=phone2&lw=1&mkt=es-MX&nopa=2&psi=skype&uaid=9fd2f7c2d3254bd3bf0ece157823be1b&coa=1&scope=service::lw.skype.com::MBI_SSL&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.live.com%2Foauth20_desktop.srf'
    at rejectAndCleanup (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:7810)
    at EventEmitter.navigationListener (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:8116)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:538:35) {
  errno: -3,
  code: 'ERR_ABORTED',
  url: 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?app_version=8.112.0.206&client_flight=ReservedFlight33,suhs&client_id=00000000480BC46C&cobrandid=6e63daac-8dfe-43f6-b70e-deacb69a89d6&display=touch&fl=phone2&lw=1&mkt=es-MX&nopa=2&psi=skype&uaid=9fd2f7c2d3254bd3bf0ece157823be1b&coa=1&scope=service::lw.skype.com::MBI_SSL&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.live.com%2Foauth20_desktop.srf'
}
[10565:0206/002316.172598:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
[10565:0206/002316.186392:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 2 times!
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 34: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 35: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 35: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 35: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 36: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 36: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
[10565:0206/002320.299116:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 3 times!
```

I'm guessing it's a graphics card drivers issue? In that case should I reinstall them? how?

This is my graphics card as per `lspci` command:

```
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c4)
```

I don't know if any other information about my system is needed to help me, in that case please let me know. Thanks in advance!

[image: what spotify looks like]

Comment: To see which driver is in use, please run `lspci -vv | grep -A13 "VGA comp" | grep Kernel` thanks.

Comment: Have you tried disabling hardware acceleration in those programs?

Comment: @mchid the result of that command is the following:
        `Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
 Kernel modules: amdgpu`

Comment: @DanielT I haven't, how should I proceed to do that?

Comment: It looks like it's complaining about libva not being found. Does `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install $(apt-cache search libva- | awk '{print $1}')` install anything? The `apt-cache search libva-` returns a list of related packages, awk prints only the first column which is the package names to install.

Comment: @mchid it did install something.  `libffi-dev libset-scalar-perl libva-dev libva-glx2 libwayland-bin
  libwayland-dev` But spotify still looks the same after reboot.

Comment: @mchid finally after reinstalling spotify, it now works fine, thanks a lot! but vlc still looks bad, same as skype, even after reinstalling. any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps it was some kind of shader cache. What if you delete `~/.cache`?